# DetailsView bug when binding an empty datatable?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am using .net 4.5 and I found this odd behaviour:

Markup:

```
<asp:DetailsView ID="dtvTest" AutoGenerateRows="true" DefaultMode="Insert" runat="server" />
```

Code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable("Test");
    dt.Columns.Add("Column", typeof(string));
    // If I uncomment the line it works!
    // dt.Rows.Add("row 1");
    dtvTest.DataSource = dt;
    dtvTest.DataBind(); 
}
```

the result is

> Collection cannot be null. Parameter name: c

thrown on dtvTest.DataBind().

If there is at least one row it works!! (see the commented line).

Any idea on how to fix/work around it?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have faced the same prob in a recent project of mine I solved it by binding empty rows colleciton as Follows , (btw I compiled it at ur solution and it works just fine)

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       DataTable dt = new DataTable("Test");
        dt.Columns.Add("Column", typeof(string));

        // If I uncomment the line it works!
        // dt.Rows.Add("row 1");

       dt.LoadDataRow(new string[1],true);
        dtvTest.DataSource = dt;

        dtvTest.DataBind();

    }
```

and also no matter how many columns you add it still works.

regards

Comment: Thanks @King A.Majid. This was not the solution but helped me. I updated the acceptChanges flag and called reject changes after binding the detailsview (I don't want the empty row).

Comment: my pleasure we are all in the same geek world of programming

Comment: I'm think I may be running into this bug, my question is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23896437/insert-into-an-empty-database-table-using-asp-net