# Insert into an empty database table using asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

From an asp.net web app using a DetailsView control, I can allow users to insert rows into our SQL database table. However, if the table is empty, the DetailsView will throw an error when it changes to insert mode. There error occurs in `System.Collections.ArrayList.InsertRange(Int32 index, ICollection c) +10647211`:

> **Description**: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> **Exception** Details: System.ArgumentNullException: Collection cannot be null. Parameter name: c

I can manually create the DetailsView `<EmptyDataTemplate>` to insert into a specific table, but I'm working with a myriad of tables that are chosen on the fly by the user.

My DetailsView and GridView controls automatically generate views according to the table the user chooses. I would like an insert control which automatically generates text boxes/labels depending on which table the users selects.

Is there a way to avoid having to create templates for each empty table to allow inserts?

Edit: 
My DetailsView control is using a LinqDataSource, and if I try binding to an empty table, I get the same ArugmentNullException error.

Comment: @DavidJBarnes I've updated my question with the error. Thank you.

Comment: This question mentions that this could be a bug with .NET. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16303018/detailsview-bug-when-binding-an-empty-datatable

Answer (score 0):

Use a [FormView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.formview%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) control. It will allow you to insert new rows if the table is empty.

Comment: Yeah, but wouldn't I still have to outline a template for each empty table? Like my DetailsView and GridView, I would like the FormView to automatically generate according to the table the user chooses.

Comment: I think I jumped the gun with my answer. I'm thinking the Null Reference Exception you were getting is probably a logical error during postback. How about posting how you're binding to the database tables and whether you're using custom data access logic or an ObjectDataSource/SqlDataSource?

Comment: The DetailsView is using a LinqDataSource

Answer (score 0):

I found my own workaround, it's an ugly solution, but it'll do.

I added some SQLDataSources which insert temporary dummy records whenever the user goes to make an insert into an empty table. Having a dummy record present allows the DetailsView control to DataBind, and then it gets deleted when it's no longer needed.

This solution will not work for any new empty tables added to the database. And the effects of having a temporary dummy record, even for a short amount of time, aren't fully known.